Uniqueness of the interpolation polynomial of a function and its derivative, and equivalent conditions.
I'm currently studying Numerical Analysis and my professor gave us an assignment which has a question that I don't think I'm answering correctly.
Consider $\{x_0,\ldots,x_n\}$ a set of $n+1$ different nodes and $y_0,\ldots,y_n,y'_0,\ldots,y'_n \in \mathbb{R}.$
Let $E$ be a vector space of real functions of $C^1([a,b])$, with $\dim E = 2n+2.$
The question consists of the following.
Given a basis $(\varphi_0,...,\varphi_{2n+1})$ of the vector space $E$, show that the following conditions are equivalent:

$ \forall \ y_0,...,y_n,y'_0,...,y'_n \ \in \mathbb{R} \ \exists^1 \ p \in E: p(x_i)=y_i \land p'(x_i)=y'_i, \ i=0,...,n.$

If $p \in E$ satisfies $p(x_i)=p'(x_i)=0, \ i=0,...,n$, then, $p \equiv 0.$

The Vandermonde matrix
$$V= \begin{bmatrix} \varphi_0(x_0) & \ldots & \varphi_{2n+1}(x_0) \\\varphi'_0 (x_0) & \ldots & \varphi'_{2n+1}(x_0)  \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\\varphi_0 (x_n) & \ldots & \varphi_{2n+1} (x_n) \\ \varphi'_0 (x_n) & \ldots &\varphi'_{2n+1} (x_n) \end{bmatrix}$$


is invertible.
My only doubt is if I proved that the Vandermonde matrix is surjective and, consequently, bijective, in the correct way. The argument I made doesn't seem very strong.
Let us see that the validity of condition a) implies the validity of condition b).
Suppose that
$$ \forall \ y_0,...,y_n,y'_0,...,y'_n \ \in \mathbb{R} \ \exists^1 \ p \in E: p(x_i)=y_i \land p'(x_i)=y'_i, \ i=0,...,n.$$
Consider $p \in E$ such that
$$p(x_i)=0 \land p'(x_i)=0,\ 1 \leq i \leq n.$$
Let $q \in E$ such that $q \equiv 0$ and $q' \equiv 0.$
By condition a),
$$p \equiv q \equiv 0.$$
Let us, now, see that the validity of condition b) implies that condition c) is true.
Suppose that if $p \in E$ satisfies $p(x_i)=p'(x_i)=0, \ i=0,...,n$, then, $p \equiv 0.$
In this case, we get the following Vandermonde system of equations.
$$\begin{bmatrix} \varphi_0(x_0) & \ldots & \varphi_{2n+1}(x_0) \\\varphi'_0 (x_0) & \ldots & \varphi'_{2n+1}(x_0)  \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\\varphi_0 (x_n) & \ldots & \varphi_{2n+1} (x_n) \\ \varphi'_0 (x_n) & \ldots &\varphi'_{2n+1} (x_n) \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} a_0 \\ a'_0 \\ \vdots \\ a_n \\ a'_n \end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}.$$
This implies that $\ker (V) = 0$, therefore, the linear application which the Vandermonde matrix represents is injective.
Given that we are working with a basis of $E$, $r(V)=2n+2.$ On the other hand $V \in \mathcal{M}_{(2n+2) \times (2n+2)} (\mathbb{R}).$
Now, we can conclude that the application in question is surjective. Thus, it is bijective, that is, it is invertible.
Therefore, $V$ is invertible.
Finally, let us see that if condition c) is true, then, condition a) is also true.
Suppose that the Vandermonde matrix
$$V= \begin{bmatrix} \varphi_0(x_0) & \ldots & \varphi_{2n+1}(x_0) \\\varphi'_0 (x_0) & \ldots & \varphi'_{2n+1}(x_0)  \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\\varphi_0 (x_n) & \ldots & \varphi_{2n+1} (x_n) \\ \varphi'_0 (x_n) & \ldots &\varphi'_{2n+1} (x_n) \end{bmatrix}$$
is invertible.
Thus the solution to the Vandermonde system of equations
$$\begin{bmatrix} \varphi_0(x_0) & \ldots & \varphi_{2n+1}(x_0) \\\varphi'_0 (x_0) & \ldots & \varphi'_{2n+1}(x_0)  \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\\varphi_0 (x_n) & \ldots & \varphi_{2n+1} (x_n) \\ \varphi'_0 (x_n) & \ldots &\varphi'_{2n+1} (x_n) \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} a_0 \\ a'_0 \\ \vdots \\ a_n \\ a'_n \end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix} y_0 \\ y'_0 \\ \vdots \\ y_n \\ y'_n \end{bmatrix}$$
is unique, $\forall \ y_0,\ldots,y_n,y'_0,\ldots,y'_n \in \mathbb{R}.$
Therefore, the coefficients $a_0,\ldots,a_n,a'_0,\ldots,a'_n$ are unique. Thus, $p \in E$ is also unique. $\blacksquare$

I don't understand what the phrase "Given that we are working with a basis of $E$, $r(V)=2n+2$." means. For some $x_i$ and $E$ it is possible to have a non-invertible matrix here, even though we work with a basis of $E$.
To get $r(V) = 2n + 2$ you can invoke the rank-nullity theorem, which in this case says that $r(V) = (2n + 2) - \dim \ker V = 2n + 2$.

But to use the rank-nullity theorem I would have to be working linear transformations, which is not guaranteed.

What do you mean? A $(2n + 2) \times (2n + 2)$ matrix always defines a linear map $\mathbb{R}^{2n + 2} \to \mathbb{R}^{2n + 2}$.

Oh! I didn't remember that. Thank you!
